# What would be the output. visibility and scope concept

Tags: c++

I don't understand how the function output when compile the code is the following:

```
0
1
1
```

I tried looking at this and every time I only see the output as:

```
1
1
1
```

Is there something I am missing? I know it's something simple I'm overlooking.

```
int foo(int a);
int x =0;
int main(){

    int x = 4;
    int y=1;
    x=foo(x);
    cout << x << endl;

    cout << foo(y) << endl;

    x=foo(x);
    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}

int foo(int n){

    if(x==n){
        return n--;
    }
    else
    return x++;
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the first `1` from?

Comment: You have two variables called `x`.

Comment: This actually prints `0 0 1 1 1` Btw, this `return n--;` doesn't make sense there.

Comment: the first x = foo(x) will pass x as 4. Then, in the function definition down the if statement (0 != 4) so x will be incremented by 1 ( the global x=0)

Comment: @hazemnaceur Yes `x` will be incremented by one, but before that happens `x` will be printed (when it's still zero).

Comment: @hazemnaceur Well now the code has been editted. I'm voting to close,

Comment: @john x = foo(x) is executed before the cout function. So it should increment first

Comment: I edited the code cuz it added an additional cout by mistake

Comment: @hazemnaceur The `foo` function also contained a cout statement, until it was editted by you.

Comment: I think the confusion you are experiencing is due to the return being x++ instead of ++x; x is being returned before it is incremented.

Comment: @AndrewL Oh I get how the first output is o. But, what about the second? shouldn't it also be zero since x is returned before it's incremented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is a bit confusing but will try to add some comments to explain what is happening. The primary confusion comes from how foo() returns x++ instead of ++x which returns the value before incrementing the global value.

```
int foo(int a);
int x =0;
int main(){

    int x = 4;
    int y=1;
    x=foo(x); // this returns 0 because global x has not been incremented yet. 
    cout << x << endl; // local x is 0 at time of assignment

    cout << foo(y) << endl; // local y == 1 and global x == 1, so foo() executes n--
                            // this returns 1 and the post-decrement only affects the 
                            // local variable within foo()

    x=foo(x);  // local x is 0, global x is 1 so return global x before incrementing
    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}

int foo(int n){

    if(x==n){
        return n--;
    }
    else
    return x++;
}
```